# Algorithm to assign best value between points based on distance

Tags: algorithm, distance

I am having trouble figuring out an algorithim to best assign values to different points on a diagram based on the distance between the points.

Essentially, I am given a diagram with a block and a dynamic amount of points. It should look something like this:

[image]

I am then given a list of values to assign to each point. Here are the rules and info:

1. I know the Lat,Long values for each point and the central block. In other words, I can get the direct distance from every object to another.
2. The list of values may be shorter that the total number of points. In this case, values can be repeated multiple times.
3. In the case where values must be repeated, the duplicate values should be as far away as possible from one another.

Here is an example using a value list of {1,2}:

[image]

In reality, this is a very simple example. In truth, there may be thousands of points.

Comment: What are the lines on the image? And what are you optimizing? Maximize the minimum distance between any two same color point, or maximizing the sum of distances between same colored points?

Comment: How does the the block interfere with other info? For now it looks like the box doesn't matter at all

Comment: Lat,Lon suggest points on some spheroid. Is it really the case, or do you mean X,Y on a Cartesian plane?

Comment: how dynamic points are (frequency of update)? what's your hardware?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out how many values you need to repeat, in your example you have 2 values and 5 points so, you need to have 2 repetition for 2 values, then you will have 2x2=4 positions [call this pNum] (you have to use different pairs as much as possible so that they are far apart from each other).
2. Calculate a [distance array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix) then find the max pNum values in the array, in other words find the greates 4 values in the array in your example.
3. assigne the repeated values for the the points found most far apart, and assign the rest of the points based on the array distance values.